# How to connect QGIS with Visual Basic?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

I'm an final student at one university, i need to make one project to make web based GIS application using open source. I select Quantum to make this project. Here i want to ask anyone, how to connect QGIS with VB to create the application that can be connect with data in QGIS. I want to create application that can be make some query from that.

I'm trying to make web based application about house rental. so i want to create some application that can be make some query of that data. for example, i want create button that people can be select where are the area they need and how much the rental house they need.

Answer (score 4):

The QGIS API is available for C++ and there are bindings for Python. There are no bindings for VB.

Maybe there is a better solution if you provide more detail on what you are actually trying to achieve.

The usual approach in open source web mapping is to use a map server - can be QGIS Server, Geoserver, or UMN Mapserver for example - and a Javascript library like OpenLayers. I don't see where VB would fit in. Do you have to use it?

Comment: i'm trying to make web based application about house rental. so i want to create some application that can be make some query of that data. for example, i want create button that people can be select where are the area they need and how much the rental house they need...so what r ur opinion???

Comment: i'm not set to use it...so what are the software suitable with this quantum to making a web based...

Comment: I already wrote down my suggestions. Check for other questions on how to start web mapping to learn about other options.